# How to sort an object according to week days name in ascending order, but array should start with today day name

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object

```
data{
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Monday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"}
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Sunday", Desc: "09:00 AM-11:30 PM"}
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Wednesday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"}
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Friday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"}
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Tuesday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"}
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Thursday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"}
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Saturday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"}
}
```

Now i want this to sort with week name in ascending order, but i think i need more is that sorting order order should start with today day name.

for example if today is Friday then it should be 
1 Friday
2 Saturday
3 Sunday
4 Monday
5 Tuesday
6 Wednesday
7 Thursday

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort with a previous check if the day value is smaller than the wanted start day.

```js
function sort(array, firstDay) {
    var order = { Monday: 1, Tuesday: 2, Wednesday: 3, Thursday: 4, Friday: 5, Saturday: 6, Sunday: 7 },
        first = order[firstDay];

    return array.sort(({ Day: a }, { Day: b }) =>
        (order[a] < first) - (order[b] < first) || order[a] - order[b]);
}

var data = [{ IsOpen: true, Day: "Monday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM" }, { IsOpen: true, Day: "Sunday", Desc: "09:00 AM-11:30 PM" }, { IsOpen: true, Day: "Wednesday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM" }, { IsOpen: true, Day: "Friday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM" }, { IsOpen: true, Day: "Tuesday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM" }, { IsOpen: true, Day: "Thursday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM" }, { IsOpen: true, Day: "Saturday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM" }];

console.log(sort(data, 'Friday'));
console.log(sort(data, 'Monday'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create array of days names and use `new Date().getDay()` to get index of today's day within the week. Then adjust the day names array accordingly by moving days before today to end of array

Finally sort data by comparing index of each object's `Day` within the adjusted day names array

```js
let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  todayIndex = new Date().getDay();// returns 0-6

// move days before today to end of array
days = days.concat(days.splice(0, todayIndex));
// sort by index in days array
data.sort((a, b) => days.indexOf(a.Day) - days.indexOf(b.Day));

console.log('Days:', JSON.stringify(days))
console.log('Data:', data)
```

```html
<script>

const data=[
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Monday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"},
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Sunday", Desc: "09:00 AM-11:30 PM"},
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Wednesday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"},
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Friday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"},
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Tuesday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"},
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Thursday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"},
    {IsOpen: true, Day: "Saturday", Desc: "09:00 AM-5:00 PM"},
]
</script>
```